# Running Elasticsearch within Gitlab CI as non-root user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Since version 6 it's not possible anymore to start Elasticsearch as a root user. Before that, there was `es.insecure.allow.root` flag which could be used for that. Now due to security reasons the ES team decided to disable that option completely.

The problem arises when you use Gitlab CI runner based on docker executor and you want to run Elasticsearch in it. `script` section of your CI job is executed by root user. Changing the user is not possible when using docker executor. Starting ES as root is not allowed. So how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an answer so I'm going to post  one here. I encountered this problem on my Ruby on Rails project so this example will be based on RoR. I had to run elasticsearch from the inside of RSpec and https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-extensions gem helped me with that. Configuring the gem is a bit out of the scope so I'm going to skip this part.

The key is to create a new non-root user inside the docker image you're using for Gitlab CI. This means using a custom image or updating your image if you're using a custom one already.

The following is the example that worked for me.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-stretch

# install elasticsearch
RUN wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.5.2-amd64.deb
RUN wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.5.2-amd64.deb.sha512
RUN shasum -a 512 -c elasticsearch-7.5.2-amd64.deb.sha512
RUN dpkg -i elasticsearch-7.5.2-amd64.deb

# adjust ownership and permissions to make it possible to run elasticsearch as a custom user
RUN chmod -R 750 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
RUN chmod -R 770 /var/log/elasticsearch
RUN chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /usr/share/elasticsearch
RUN chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /var/log/elasticsearch
RUN chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /var/lib/elasticsearch
RUN chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /etc/default/elasticsearch
RUN chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /etc/elasticsearch

# create a user and add it to elasticsearch group
RUN useradd non_root -m
RUN usermod -a -G elasticsearch non_root

# select this user to make it run gitlab script section instead of root
USER non_root
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: your_image

your_job:
  script:
    # run elasticsearch here
```